# BIgquery to elasticsearch (Avoid adding duplicate documents to elasticsearch.)

Tags: elasticsearch, google-bigquery

I am trying to sync data between Bigquery and elasticsearch using the job template provided in GCP. The issue is that Bigquery sends all the documents everytime the job is run, now as elasticsearch has the document id as _id ,it creates duplicate documents.
Is there a way by which we can configure data _id field while sending data from bigquery to elasticsearch.

Comment: If they have the same id, they should be overwritten and not duplicated. Do you have an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: they don't have the same _id as I am not able to configure that on gcp while sending data